# QUERY sem resultado esperado, o que pode está faltando?

Tags: mysql, sql

Complementando com atuais informações, entendi o resultado atual, e o que parece é informações duplicadas mesmo, mas em tabelas diferentes, mas isso nem é comigo pois já cheguei e estava assim e ainda sou estagiário estou apenas estudando esse banco. Ainda estou buscando compreender melhor o uso dos JOINS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

===========================================================

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT p.idPessoa AS ID_PESSOA,
       p.nome AS TITULAR,
       d.idDependente AS ID_DEPENDENTE,
       d.nome AS DEPENDENTE,
       c.valorAuxilio AS VALOR_AUXILIO
FROM sca_pessoa p

INNER JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
INNER JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%' AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 AND c.valorAuxilio IS NOT NULL;
```

Eu gostaria que tivesse o seguinte resultado: NOME TITULAR, NOME DEPENDENTE e VALOR de AUXILIO que seria o valor de cada um (2x pessoas) conforme a tabela abaixo.

A tabela de nome **sispro_contrato** tem o valores conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: SELECT idSituacaoContrato, valorAuxilio, idDependente FROM sispro_contrato where idPessoa = 1361;]

O que estaria errado ou faltando?

Se eu tirar o **AND c.valorAuxilio <> null** o retorno fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem as estruturas das tabelas:

```
sca_pessoa

idPessoa                     int(10) unsigned
matricula                    varchar(45)
nome                         varchar(100)
telefoneResidencial          char(13)
telefoneCelular              char(13)
telefoneUnidade              char(13)
email                        varchar(100)
dtAdmissao                   date
dtNascimento                 date
idSituacao                   int(4)
SalarioReferencia            int(10) unsigned
idCargo                      int(10)
idLotacao                    int(11)
cpf                          varchar(45)
codigoLotacao                varchar(45)
funcaoValorInicialVertical   varchar(45)
funcaoValorInicialHorizontal varchar(45)
idFuncao                     int(11) unsigned
sexo                         char(1)
rg                           varchar(15)
nomePai                      varchar(44)
nomeMae                      varchar(44)
gsanguineo                   varchar(3)
rh                           varchar(3)
ativo                        char(1)


sca_dependente

idDependente        int(10) unsigned
idPessoa            int(11) unsigned
nome                varchar(100)
dtNascimento        date
idParentesco        int(11) unsigned
pensionista         tinyint(3) unsigned
universitario       tinyint(3) unsigned
pne                 tinyint(3) unsigned
comprovanteEscolar  tinyint(3)


sispro_contrato

idContrato                   int(10) unsigned
idOperadora                  int(10) unsigned
proposta                     varchar(45)
ans                          varchar(45)
valor                        decimal(10,2)
idPessoa                     int(10) unsigned
idFormaDePagamento           int(10) unsigned
idSituacaoContrato           int(10) unsigned
idOperadorUltimaAtualizacao  varchar(45)
dataContrato                 date
dataEncaminhamento           date
dataDeferimento              date
dataHoraUltimaAlteracao      datetime
dataRequerimento             date
dataSituacaoAtual            date
dataSuspensao                date
dataCancelamento             date
idProcesso                   int(11) unsigned
valorAuxilio                 decimal(10,2)
idDependente                 int(10) unsigned
idOperador                   varchar(45)
idTipoOperadora              int(10) unsigned
valorTotalAuxilio            decimal(10,2)
```

Comment: Observação que não foi é que a QUERY acima não retorna nada, sendo que o que eu queria de retorno seria apenas NOME, DEPENDENTE e VALOR AUXILIO que seria esses dois últimos.

Comment: Acredito que vc esteja fazendo o `inner join` de maneira errada.

Comment: @Bacco gostaria de te perguntar só uma coisa sobre uso do JOINS, que não entendi bem e fiquei em duvida. O uso dos JOINS será aplicado apenas nas tabelas que possuem relacionamento, ou seja uma PK para uma FK, ou simplesmente entre duas PK o que não faz sentido de fato. Então quando eu usar ... ON tabA.idPessoa = tabB.idPessoa(Que é uma FK) é tipo isso?

Comment: @phpricardo Se for o caso de tirar o accept da minha resposta, não vejo problemas, visto que não está resolvido o problema, mas de qualquer forma acho bom isolar cada parte do problema e clarificar a dúvida. Até agora acho que não deu pra entender como você quer que sumam as duas linhas, já que as mesmas estão na base de dados pelo que tudo indica.

Comment: O ON do join é pra dizer em que condiçoes as duas colunas vão aparecer no mesmo resultado. Chegou a ver esse link? [Qual é a diferença entre inner join e outer join](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Comment: Sim, mas não entendi essa questão minha.

Comment: @phpricardo se estao aparecendo duas linhas por pessoa, pode ser um problema no join ou na base de dados. Será que esse Ademar não tem realmente dois contratos diferentes pra essas duas pessoas? Seria bom você levantar essas questões todas. Como deveria aparecer? Qual é a certa, a Cícera de 109 ou a de 269? É pra somar os valores, ou é pra pegar um só deles? Se for um só, qual?

Comment: @phpricardo uma coisa que pode estar errada realmente é o ON. Poste a estrutura das tabelas, de repente não estamos conseguindo notar algo por causa disso. Talvez o ID correto não seja o idPessoa dos dois lados

Comment: É um pouco grande @Bacco posso colocar as desc das tabelas aqui mesmo?

Comment: Aqui está para download https://copy.com/UCMoq8uJx24g

Comment: @phpricardo Sempre que você postar em formato de código, quando é comprido aparece barra de rolagem. Mas como link ja ajuda.

Comment: Mesmo lendo as duas perguntas, ainda não está claro o que você quer. Por favor edite a pergunta com a saída esperada.

Comment: @phpricardo, acho que você ainda não tem isso claro: a rede [se] ***é muito diferente*** do fóruns tradicionais. Aqui, "resolvido" é a resposta marcada como correta pelo autor da pergunta, e a "utilidade" é para toda internet. Uma vez que você publica seu problema aqui, ele já não é mais "seu". Por isso, tenha cuidado com o código da sua empresa e a licença `cc by sa` que todo material postado aqui ganha automaticamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
SELECT p.nome AS NOME,
       d.nome AS DEPENDENTE,
       c.valorAuxilio AS VALOR_AUXILIO
FROM sca_pessoa p

-- Mantive o left join, mas no exemplo dado nao vem ao caso.
LEFT JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
LEFT JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%' AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 AND c.valorAuxilio IS NOT NULL;
```

O que tem de diferente aí é o seguinte:

- Acertada a comparação IS NOT NULL.
  Use sempre IS NULL e IS NOT NULL em vez de comparação com `<` `>` `=`. Nulos não são "comparáveis".
- Arrumada a sintaxe do `JOIN` e `ON`

> Veja a diferença entre os tipos de JOIN aqui:
>   **[Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)**

De qualquer forma, se a sua base de dados tiver mais de um dependente por pessoa, vai retornar com certeza mais de uma linha por nome. Aí só agrupando, mas no caso você não deve mostrar o nome do dependente, pois vai ser mais de um:

```
SELECT p.idPessoa AS ID_PESSOA,
   p.nome AS TITULAR,
   SUM(c.valorAuxilio) AS VALOR_AUXILIO_TOTAL
FROM sca_pessoa p

INNER JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
INNER JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%' AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 AND c.valorAuxilio IS NOT NULL
-- agrupar pelo titular:
GROUP BY p.idPessoa
-- OU agrupar pelo titular E dependente (use um dos GROUPs so):
GROUP BY p.idPessoa, d.idDependente
```

Comment: Sem erro, mas nenhum retorno Bacco.

Comment: Sim, as colunas sim.

Comment: Bacco adicionei uma imagem lá em cima, mas tentei com dessa maneira e tem o mesmo resultado (da imagem)

Comment: No último print que anexei ele mostra 4 resultados sendo duplicados no valor de auxilio, mas o que quero é que mostre apenas dois. Sendo que irá ser de R$269,35 e o outro R$109,94.

Comment: Puxa, mas aí você está mudando completamente a pergunta. Seu JOIN está errado entao. Editei novamente a resposta. Você quer um LEFT JOIN e não inner.

Comment: @phpricardo Incluí um link para você conferir melhor os tipos principais de join. Veja lá qual tipo é o que realmente atende sua necessidade.

Comment: peço desculpas pela falta de compreensão do meu problema, porque para falar a verdade nem eu também sei bem como explicar isso sou apenas estagiário aqui na empresa, já li algumas coisas sobre os JOINS, mas é que ainda tenho umas duvidas. Quando adicionei o left join nada mudou a não ser a ordem, mas continuo tendo valores duplos.

Comment: Mas então estes valores estão realmente vinculado ao mesmo ID. Como é que você saberia dizer qual dos dois é o certo? Precisa ver se a base de dados está correta também. É que fica um pouco complicado entender sem ver os dados originais e como foi organizado.

Comment: O que eu ainda entendi aqui nesse banco que estou mexendo é que essa tabela sispro_contrato ela é meio que relacionada a várias outras e me disseram que é recomendável eu usar ela para coletar informações das outras, entende? Então com o ID da pessoa eu puxo através dela (tabela contrato) informações dos dependentes, ou coisa assim. :(

Comment: É eu imagino que seja complicado mesmo saber o que fazer sem ver o que é ao vivo. :|

Comment: Eu só nao tirei ela da query por que ela está sendo usada aqui ->  `AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3`

Comment: Hmm é, mas nada ainda do que quero. Vou ver o que faço aqui ainda. O fato que está um pouco complexo talvez para eu explicar mesmo.

Comment: @phpricardo recomendaria você antes de mais nada entender o que você precisa fazer, aí ir montando a query aos poucos e experimentando uma parte por vez. Se tentar acertar todas as condições ao mesmo tempo vai ficar doido aí e não vai saber qual parte está errada. Troque os campos do select por SELECT *, pra ver tudo, tire os AS isso e AS aquilo, pra enxergar melhor o nome dos campos, e depois vá pondo os WHERE e os agrupamentos. Assim que dominar a situação, vá pondo de volta as coisas que faltam.

Comment: vou ver isso mesmo cara, eu até sei o que quero, mas acho que falta de conhecimento está me bloqueando mesmo. Mas agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @phpricardo quando tiver dominado o essencial e esbarrar numa complicação maior, volte aqui e pergunte, que sempre tem alguém pra ajudar, mas lembre que o melhor jeito de aprender é entendendo cada parte do problema separadamente.

Answer (score 2):

Se uma dessas tabelas `sca_dependente` ou `sispro_contrato`  tiver mais de um registro, sua consulta trará tantos registros de pessoa quanto existirem nessas tabelas auxiliares.

Desta forma, recomendo que vc agrupe o resultado pelo que interessa:

```
SELECT p.idPessoa AS ID_PESSOA,
   p.nome AS TITULAR,
   d.idDependente AS ID_DEPENDENTE,
   d.nome AS DEPENDENTE,
   SUM(c.valorAuxilio) AS VALOR_AUXILIO
FROM sca_pessoa p

INNER JOIN sca_dependente d ON p.idPessoa = d.idPessoa
INNER JOIN sispro_contrato c ON p.idPessoa = c.idPessoa

WHERE p.nome LIKE '%ADEMAR MAGA%' AND c.idSituacaoContrato = 3 AND c.valorAuxilio IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY p.idPessoa,
   p.nome,
   d.idDependente,
   d.nome
```